# Importance of an edge regarding distances

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, data-mining, network-analysis, social-networks

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and any edge $(u,v) \in E$, let us denote by $G_{(u,v)}=(V,E\setminus\{(u,v)\})$ obtained from $G$ by removing this edge.

I am interested in the difference between the average distance in $G$ and $G_{(u,v)}$ (or equivalently the sum of all distances in these graphs).

This value is a feature of the edge in the graph that quantifies its importance in a way similar to what [betweenness centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) does, but it is different.

Hence my question: is it used anywhere as a centrality measure? or in any other context?